# Determining number of common elements between all arrays in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a data structure like this:

```
id | array
-------------
 1 | {1,2,3,4}
 2 | {1,2,4,5}
 3 | {1,5,6,7}
 4 | {4,5,6,8}
```

Each array has the same number of elements. I want to know for every two-row combination the number of elements *in the same position* that are identical between the two. So for instance, {1,2,3,4} and {2,3,4,5} would have zero elements in common (because they are not in the same position), and {1,2,3,4} and {1,2,3,5} would have three elements in common. So the results of the above would look something like:

```
row_ids | common
----------------
{1,2}   |      2
{1,3}   |      1
{1,4}   |      0
{2,3}   |      1
{2,4}   |      0
{3,4}   |      2
```

Is this possible in Postgres, or do I need to import all the data into Python and do it in memory there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unnest the arrays in a common table expression while keeping track of the index of each element, using handy option `with ordinality`.

Then you can self-join the resultset, aggregate and count elements that are equal, position-wise.

One advantage of this approach is that it would properly handle arrays of different sizes.

```
with cte as (
    select t.id, a.elem, a.nr
    from mytable t
    cross join lateral unnest(t.ar) with ordinality as a(elem, nr)
)
select 
    array[c1.id, c2.id] row_ids, 
    sum( (c1.nr = c2.nr and c1.elem = c2.elem)::int ) common
from cte c1
inner join cte c2 on c1.id < c2.id
group by c1.id, c2.id
order by c1.id, c2.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a06b99bbd74dc889ee2958407e8f4ba)**:

```
row_ids | common
:------ | -----:
{1,2}   |      2
{1,3}   |      1
{1,4}   |      0
{2,3}   |      1
{2,4}   |      0
{3,4}   |      2
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much, elegant solution.